# c# “Syntax Error in From Clause” with Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm getting “Syntax Error in From Clause” when using
the simple query `SELECT * FROM Order`.
The weird thing is that I use this query many times during my project.
I'm using `SELECT * FROM Suppliers` and it works just fine, all the tables are connected to the same Access file.

Comment: `ORDER` is a keyword, you need to escape it:  `SELECT * FROM [Order]`

Answer (score 4):

`order` is an `sql` keyword, use with brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM [Order]
```

Answer (score 4):

`Order` is a reserve word and thus needs escaping like

```
SELECT * FROM "Order"
```

(OR)

```
SELECT * FROM [Order]
```

Better, never name a DB object with reserve word or keyword. If you really have to then try like `tblOrder`